# subquery not returning distinct results

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I've not written SQL for a couple of years and feel I'm missing something obvious, but can't figure it out!...
I'm using an SQL query window in PGADMIN 3 version 1.22.2
I want to get a sum from a subquery to return a value into my main query; the main query is based on filtering a customer table and the subquery a qty of goods sold for a specific period and meeting multiple criteria.
This is what I have a the moment:

```
select customerid, account, name,
-- Aluminium
(select sum(qty_inv) from ainvdet
 where inv_account = CUST.account
  and sales_year = 2021
  and line_type = 'S'
  and layout_section = 'D'
  and qty_inv > 0
  and ((product_group like 'IN%' and (part like '%H01%' or description like 
      '%H01%')) 
   or (part like 'DCA40%' or part like 'DCA60%' or part like 'D5432%' or part 
      like 'D5433%' or part like 'D5434%' or part like '220392%' or part like 
      '220360%' or part like 'D1106%' or part like 'DL510%' or part like 
      'DL508%' or part like 'DL509%' or part like 'DL507%' or part like 
      'DT693%' or part like 'DL608%' or part like 'DL205%' or part like 
      'SPET%' or part like 'XOET%') 
   or ((part like 'E24%' and (part like '%AL%' or part like '%AZ%')) or (part 
      like 'E25%' and (part like '%AL%' or part like '%AZ%')) or part like 
      'E70%' or  part like 'E71%' or part like 'LANCIA%' or part like 
      'TC163%' or part like 'TC622%' or part like 'TE943%' or part like 
      'TE953%') 
   or ((part like '%H01%' or description like '%H01%') and product_group in 
      ('LTTU','LTGR','LTPO')))) as "Aluminium", 
-- Steel
(select sum(qty_inv) from ainvdet 
 where inv_account = CUST.account 
 and sales_year = 2021 
 and line_type = 'S' 
 and layout_section = 'D' 
 and qty_inv > 0  
 and ((product_group in ('MCXP','MCXX','MC4G')) 
 OR (product_group like 'IN%' and (part like '%PC3500%' OR part like
    '%PC3600%' OR description like '%PC3500%' OR description like '%PC3600%'))      
 or (part like '%DH406%' or part like '%DH408%' or part like '%DH421%') 
 or (product_group = 'DRUD' and (part like '%PC3500%' or description like 
   '%PC3500%')) 
 or (product_group in ('LTPO','LTGR') and (part like '%NC3220%' or 
    description like '%NC3220%' or part like '%NC3225%' or description like 
    '%NC3225%')) 
 or (product_group = 'LTTU' and (part like '%NC3220%' or description like 
    '%NC3220%' or part like '%NC3225%' or description like '%NC3225%' or part      
    like '%NC3215%' or description like '%NC3215%' or part like '%YG3020%' or 
    description like '%YG3020%')))
) as "Steel"


from customer CUST 
where userchk1 <> true AND  userchk2 <> true AND userchk3 <> true AND 
userchk4 <> true AND userchk5 <> true AND userchk6 <> true AND userchk7 <> 
true AND userchk8 <> true AND userchk9 <> true AND userchk10 <> true

limit 5
```

I am getting the individual fields from the customer table, but the sub queries are returning the same value for all customers.

I have also tried it with GROUP BY customerid and get the same results, like this:

[Output Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g02XJ.png)

(n.b. The limit is only to make it run faster whilst testing)

Comment: Please edit/format your querty into some readable form. [I started editing, but it is too much for me]

Comment: edited: hope it reads better wildplasser; apologies, first post.

Comment: Your query is too large to handle. Maybe conditional aggregation could simplify it?

Comment: I don't know how to streamline it or what a conditional aggregation is; please feel free to remove a lot of the 'OR' lines if it makes it more readable.  The main issue is why isn't it only returning data specific to that customer?

Comment: NOTE: the aggregating subqueries look different: `where customerid = CUST.customeri` <<-->> `where inv_account = CUST.account` . Is this intentional?

Comment: You should post your data model (create table's queries), some example data (insert queries) and the desire result; so we can execute your query. You could use something like [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/).

Answer (score 0):

Untested (obviously)

---

```
SELECT cu.customerid
        , cu.account
        , cu.name
                -- Aluminium
        , SUM(vd.qty_inv) FILTER(
                WHERE  (vd.product_group LIKE 'IN%' AND (vd.part LIKE '%H01%' OR vd.description LIKE 
                        '%H01%')) 
                        OR (vd.part LIKE 'DCA40%' OR vd.part LIKE 'DCA60%' OR vd.part LIKE 'D5432%' OR vd.part 
                        LIKE 'D5433%' OR vd.part LIKE 'D5434%' OR vd.part LIKE '220392%' OR vd.part LIKE 
                        '220360%' OR vd.part LIKE 'D1106%' OR vd.part LIKE 'DL510%' OR vd.part LIKE 
                        'DL508%' OR vd.part LIKE 'DL509%' OR vd.part LIKE 'DL507%' OR vd.part LIKE 
                        'DT693%' OR vd.part LIKE 'DL608%' OR vd.part LIKE 'DL205%' OR vd.part LIKE 
                        'SPET%' OR vd.part LIKE 'XOET%') 
                        OR ((vd.part LIKE 'E24%' AND (vd.part LIKE '%AL%' OR vd.part LIKE '%AZ%')) OR (vd.part 
                        LIKE 'E25%' AND (vd.part LIKE '%AL%' OR vd.part LIKE '%AZ%')) OR vd.part LIKE 
                        'E70%' OR  vd.part LIKE 'E71%' OR vd.part LIKE 'LANCIA%' OR vd.part LIKE 
                        'TC163%' OR vd.part LIKE 'TC622%' OR vd.part LIKE 'TE943%' OR vd.part LIKE
                        'TE953%') 
                        OR ((vd.part LIKE '%H01%' OR vd.description LIKE '%H01%') AND vd.product_group in 
                        ('LTTU','LTGR','LTPO'))
                ) as "Aluminium"
                -- Steel
        , SUM(vd.qty_inv) FILTER( 
                WHERE (vd.product_group in ('MCXP','MCXX','MC4G')) andor 
                 (vd.product_group LIKE 'IN%' AND (vd.part LIKE '%PC3500%' OR vd.part LIKE
                'PC3600%' OR vd.description LIKE '%PC3500%' OR vd.description LIKE '%PC3600%')) andor     
                 (vd.part LIKE '%DH406%' OR vd.part LIKE '%DH408%' OR vd.part LIKE '%DH421%') andor
                 (vd.product_group = 'DRUD' AND (vd.part LIKE '%PC3500%' OR vd.description LIKE 
                'PC3500%')) andor
                 (vd.product_group in ('LTPO','LTGR') AND (vd.part LIKE '%NC3220%' OR 
                vd.description LIKE '%NC3220%' OR vd.part LIKE '%NC3225%' OR vd.description LIKE 
                'NC3225%')) andor
                 (vd.product_group = 'LTTU' AND (vd.part LIKE '%NC3220%' OR vd.description LIKE 
                'NC3220%' OR vd.part LIKE '%NC3225%' OR vd.description LIKE '%NC3225%' OR vd.part      
                 '%NC3215%' OR vd.description LIKE '%NC3215%' OR vd.part LIKE '%YG3020%' OR 
                vd.description LIKE '%YG3020%'))
                 ) as "Steel" 

FROM customer cu
LEFT JOIN ainvdet vd ON vd.inv_account = cu.account
                AND vd.sales_year = 2021
                AND vd.line_type = 'S'
                AND vd.layout_section = 'D'
                AND vd.qty_inv > 0
WHERE cu.userchk1 <> true AND  cu.userchk2 <> true 
        AND cu.userchk3 <> true AND cu.userchk4 <> true 
         AND cu.userchk5 <> true AND cu.userchk6 <> true 
         AND cu.userchk7 <> true AND cu.userchk8 <> true 
         AND cu.userchk9 <> true AND cu.userchk10 <> true
GROUP BY 1,2,3
        ;
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance; however, i'm getting a syntax error at or near both sub queries at the open brackets after FILTER.
Any thoughts on what is causing the issue?
(n.b. there was 1 too many comma's in between the sub queries, but that wasn't the issue.

Comment: There are no subqueries. The `WHERE` in the filter-condition is reuse of a keyword. ("syntactic sugar") . Well: most probably, I made some trivial error. Probably omitted a comma or a table-alias somewhere...

Comment: There was an extra comma after `"Aluminium"` Fixed it.

Comment: Can't get to the bottom of it! :-(
Even if I remove the whole of the code within the brackets after WHERE it still gives the same syntax error

Comment: my first comment noted ...
(n.b. there was 1 too many comma's in between the sub queries, but that wasn't the issue

Comment: I repeat: *it is **NOT** a subquery*. It is a filter condition, which reuses the `WHERE` keyword.

Comment: I was quoting my original comment where I mistakenly called it a subquery; anyway, I have been looking online at other FILTER examples and they seem to have the brackets near to the WHERE clause after the word WHERE rather than before; when I do this to your query I still get a syntax error but it is now highlighting the error as being at the AS alias, but can't seem to get past it

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I got confused by all the parentheses.

Comment: sure, but do you have any idea why it now failing at the alias please?

Comment: There were some single quotes missing. (also in your original query, IIRC)

Comment: I have resolved all of those, but still getting the syntax at alias issue

Comment: `getting the syntax at alias issue` is not a problem description.

Comment: There are a few ANDs/ORs missing, too. Add them.

Comment: Wildplasser, just wanted to say thank you; I've managed to use part of your code and culminate it with some of my own.